# Where can I find pf Document class (pf.cls)?

Tags: document-classes

I have a `.tex` file which specifies the document class has `pf`. I searched but couldn't find the `.cls` file related to this `pf` class. Does anyone know where can I find it?

Comment: Sounds like a private class. Check with the source of your .tex file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.